# Weird Short Story Involving "City Protector"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Sometime I read this weird short story but I couldn't think of the name or the title of the book it belonged to.

So there is this person who senses the presence of something like city protector or guardian, goes to a city, meets this girl who was like, a sexologist or something, they start a relationship. One day, the girl lures him in with something about a spider in a bathtub. Sometime later, that "city protector" was killed by someone else and was cut apart and buried. 
After a while the city protector comes alive in a different Korean body and comes to tell the girl that her boyfriend was dead, but feels no love for her anymore.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have trouble following the story. Not counting the spider, there seem to be 4 characters: a girl sexologist (G), her boyfriend (B), a city protector (P), and a killer (K). Right? So B senses the presence of P (from a great distance?), goes to the city, meets G and they start a "relationship". One day G lures B in with a spider story. (If they're in a relationship, why does she need a spider to lure him in?) Later P is killed, dismembered, and buried by K. Then P comes back to life in a "different Korean body" (was P Korean to start with?), and finally P tells G that B is is dead. Is that it?

Comment: I forgot to ask: For what purpose does G lure B in with the spider story?

Comment: Sorry, That's all I could remember, B is also a city protector himself, which are entities who are very powerful but not omniscient. When they die, they come back alive in a different form. City protectors tend to compete with each other because there should be only one city protector per city. The G was just a side thing because the B's main objective was to investigate this force he feels. B is the person who was killed, and he comes back alive as the Korean. Also, K = P, sorry for not being clear.

Comment: G lures B with spider wasn't a major part of the story, just a part that was weird because G wasn't sure if B liked her and tests this by asking B to kill a spider in the bathtub, and when he came, he realized exactly why she lured him there ;)

Comment: this was edited?  I really would hate to see the unedited version.